# How to hide all console output in Panda3d?

Tags: panda3d

Whenever I start my Panda3d application, i.e. initialise the `ShowBase` class, I get the following console output:

```
Known pipe types:
  wglGraphicsPipe
(all display modules loaded.)
```

The application works fine, so I would like to suppress these lines.
How can I disable/hide this output?

Also, what does this mean exactly?

Comment: `what does this mean exactly?`

I'm not familiar with Panda3D, but to me it looks like simple status output - a list of found pipe types (which consists of a single entry in this case) and confirming that all modules loaded correctly. Why do you want to suppress those lines? Is console output even visible in the compiled/published (or whatever it is that Panda3D does) product? If not, it seems like it's not worth wasting time on. Also, a quick google tells me Panda3D is open source - so just search this text or step through the code to see where it's being printed and change that line.

Comment: Yes, of course, I know that I could look for where it is being printed to console in the sources. I thought however someone knows how to turn this output off easily...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panda loads the display modules that have been specified in the Config.prc file (through load-display and aux-display lines) and lists which ones are available for rendering. Examples are the "pandagl" module, which makes the "wglGraphicsPipe" rendering pipeline available on Windows (the OpenGL renderer), and the "pandadx8" and "pandadx9" modules (with the respective DirectX renderers).

If you really wish to hide this information, you can start Panda with "window-type none" to prevent it from creating the window, creating the pipe and opening the window explicitly, telling Panda not to output the pipe types when opening the pipe:

```
base.makeDefaultPipe(printPipeTypes=False)
base.openDefaultWindow()
```

However, there is no real reason to suppress it, as it won't appear in a deployed game (only in the log file).  You can also redirect this output to a log file yourself if you wish, by setting the "notify-out" configuration variable to a filename in your Config.prc file.